# sketch graph by given data

Tags: calculus

suppose that we are given following  data,clearly  in this case it is talking about linear form right?i meant  $y=k*x+b$ form,  in this case we can simply choose any two point for example $(1990,11)$ and $(1992,26)$,calculate  slope  and finally find
$b$,it is required right or we should do some more advanced interpolation,like least square method or  more advanced one?thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the scope of this problem is, but I think that a simple linear interpolation between two data points is probably sufficient for this problem.

**However!** this function overall might not be linear - try doing part (a) and see if you agree. If you really wanted to get a close estimate, you could try and find a curve of best fit of the right type,

> which is exponential (notice that as $t$ increases by $2$, $N$ roughly doubles),

and then use the result to estimate answers for (b). But again, I think a simple linear interpolation for (b) is probably fine.

Comment: i mean it is for recitation,which i should deliver for freshmen students,they have learned  just linear forms,i will see if they know about exponential forms

Comment: I certainly think that would add to the discussion, though the wording "sketch a *rough* graph" and then "use your graph" indicate they are probably looking for a pretty "low-tech" solution.